# why output to fifo in bash blocks and doesn't when there is redirection

Tags: bash, shell

> mkfifo fifo
>   echo 1 >fifo
>   blocks on last command.

I find a explanation of this in [gnu libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FIFO-Special-Files.html#FIFO-Special-Files)

> However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

But

```
>mkfifo fifo  
>exec 5<>fifo  
>echo 1 >&5
```

doesn't block and works well. Again AFAIK shells use a dup2 to make redirections but
how does this makes a difference?

Actually I find the answer when I formulated the question. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is short.

From my linux distro `man 7 fifo`

> Under  Linux,  opening  a  FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.

So it's due to `<>` in redirection.